# QtCreator broken native compiler messages

Tags: qt, visual-c++, qt-creator

There is a known bug in QtCreator: under Windows it cannot handle correctly compiler native messages.

When using MinGW it's all ok since it produces messages in English. But there is no Qt5 binaries for MinGW (and I don't want to build my own ones, since, I guess, it painful process). So I try to use MSVC. But, my MSVC prints error mesages in Russian. After QtCreator processes these messages it shows me something unreadable.

For now google didn't help me how to solve this problem.

Does anybody know the way to configure QtCreator? Or configure MSVC to print errors in English? Or even modify QtCreator's source putting some stub and "fixing" the problem?

Comment: Read here https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-316

Comment: Thanks. This patch to QtCreator helped. https://codereview.qt-project.org/30405 The only thing I got the error on loading image viewer plugin, but compiler output become comprehendable.